# MySql inner join returning all the results as if it's left or cross join

Tags: mysql

I have a simple query which is not giving the desired results. The query is a follows

```
select * 
from friends_nudges a 
     INNER JOIN user_friends b 
      ON a.user_id = b.user_id 
where a.user_id = 104 and 
      nudge_sent = 1 
order by nudge_sent_time asc
```

Somehow this query is returning all the results of both the tables.

Comment: Seperate the conditions and execute query like what are you getting with only doing join excluding the where condition...

Comment: @gaurav why not specify the columns that you need to show? instead of doing `*` all..

Comment: Can you post some sample data for each table and the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

Try this please:

```
select a.col, b.col -- specify accordingly
from friends_nudges a 
     INNER JOIN user_friends b 
      ON a.user_id = b.user_id 
      AND a.user_id = 104 
      AND a.nudge_sent = 1 -- where does nudge_Sent belong to? a or b?
order by a.nudge_sent_time asc -- where does this column belong to?
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry, my mistake... the user_id column is not the primary key column in both the tables that's why so many records were coming. So the basic first and foremost check point is: never forget the base rule.. all the joins should normally be done against primary and foreign keys.